# Is maths library included in the glibc now?

Tags: c, eclipse, glibc, math.h

when I try to compile this simple code from terminal:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    printf("%f\n",sqrt(10));

    return 0;
}
```

using

> gcc main.c

command, it gets compiled and a.out gives correct answer. It means that that maths functions are added in C standard library which gets linked automatically.

But if compile the same code in Eclipse IDE without adding any library to properties, it gives undefined reference error. It means maths functions are not part of C standard library.

What is the truth?

Comment: Is math.h included by stdio.h now?

Comment: The warning **does matter**. Implicit functions are dangerous, and in this case, the return type does not match, so the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: @R..: As of C99, the behavior is undefined because the call violates a constraint. The implicit `int` rule was dropped, so there is no return type.

Comment: @R.. that is correct it does matter, I was being too loose w/ my terminology there.

Comment: Please add the required `#include <math.h>`. Eclipse doesn't compile code, it invokes a compiler to do it. You may be seeing differing behavior from different compilers or from the same compiler with different options. It's impossible to tell without knowing how your Eclipse is configured.

Comment: I have not added, math.h yet I get correct answer. I get the following warning during compilation - warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘sqrt’ [enabled by default]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be seeing [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) here, where using a constant in the math function call will cause the compiler to calculate the function and omit the call to the math library all together.

If we check out the docs for [Other Built-in Functions Provided by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) says(*emphasis mine*):

> GCC includes built-in versions of many of the functions in the standard C library. The versions prefixed with _*builtin* are always treated as having the same meaning as the C library function even if you specify the -fno-builtin option. (see C Dialect Options) Many of these functions are only optimized in certain cases; **if they are not optimized in a particular case, a call to the library function is emitted.**

If we look at this [slightly modified live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32d13721bb731192) which uses the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    printf("%d\n",(int)sqrt(25));

    return 0;
}
```

we see the following assembly generated by `gcc`:

```
movl    $5, %esi        
movq    %rax, %rdi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
```

so we see `5` is moved into `esi` which in the [x64 abi](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) is the second argument to to the calling function and is the result of `sqrt(25)` there is no call to `sqrt` at all.

Note you are missing:

```
#include <math.h>
```

**Update**

Built-ins are a [gcc extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) the built-in link above explains which ones are used in which mode and they should all have the same meaning as the standard functions.

If you are concerned about your code being standards compliant then you can check out the [Options Controlling C Dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) section of the manual. You can use `-std` to specify which standard you want to comply with and `-pedantic` to enable warnings when you are using a feature that does not conform with the standard or `-pedantic-errors` to make the warnings an error. So for example using

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic
```

would generate a warning when you used a feature that was compliant with the *C99* standard for example [zero length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length).

We can also use `-fno-builtin` to disable some builtins, the documents says:

> Don't recognize built-in functions that do not begin with _*builtin* as prefix. See Other built-in functions provided by GCC, for details of the functions affected, including those which are not built-in functions when -ansi or -std options for strict ISO C conformance are used because they do not have an ISO standard meaning. [...]

Comment: Without the required `#include <math.h>` casting the result of `sqrt()` to `int` is not helpful. A pre-C99 compiler will still assume `sqrt()` returns an `int` result.

Comment: @KeithThompson Are you talking about the example I linked? Because I did include `math.h` in my live example. Or do you mean I should be more explicit when I note that the code the OP included did not?

Comment: I didn't follow the link. The example is only 10 lines. You should include it in your answer rater than linking to an external site.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour your reply is very enlightening. I tried compiling the same code with -fno-builtin option and it emitted error - undefined reference!  I also noticed by changing the source code that the built-in version of the function sqrt is available only for constants, not for variables. could you please tell me that these built-in function feature is a gcc thing, not an ansi standard?  if it is not an ansi standard, i would like to add -fno-builtin to the compilation command all the time. But I still wonder if it is builtin feature, why did eclipse rejected when it uses gcc only inside?

Comment: @Saurabh I updated my answer, I am not sure why Eclipse behaves differently it is probably a setting, I was not able to find anything specific to built-ins. The docs do not define under what conditions it omits the library call but the constant case from what understand is a simple optimization.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour options like -std=c99 -ansi -pedantic -pedantic-errors would not make a difference in this code. -fno-builtin would generate error.

Answer (score 0):

On some compiler standard library functions are **enabled by default**. On compiling

```
int main(){

    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

this code on GCC 4.7.1 it compiles giving the warnings:

```
[Warning] implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
[Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
```

Comment: The same compiler error can be obtained by replacing `printf` by `print`, and not linking (`gcc -c`): it warns about a missing header and has nothing to do with libraries.

Comment: @larsmans; . With `print` it is giving same warning but didn't compile. And it is not giving warning about `enabled by default`. I think your down vote is something intentionally.

Comment: Under C90 rules, called functions are declared implicitly as functions returning `int`. In this case, since `printf` is variadic, any call without a visible prototype has undefined behavior. Under C99 and later rules, there is no implicit `int`, and any call to a standard library function without a visible declaration is a constraint violation. gcc warns about this (which is acceptable under the standard), but IMHO it *should* just reject the program.

Comment: @KeithThompson; I know. But I want to know can we do this or not?

Comment: @KeithThompson; Sorry! I mean can I do this or not? I think doing this is OK. I tried many times on different compiler.

Comment: If you're asking about the code in your example, it has undefined behavior in C90 and is a constraint violation in C99 and later. `int main()` should be `int main(void)`. The `#include <stdio.h>` is not optional. (Well, you could declare `printf` yourself, but you still have to do it correctly.) You should print a newline at the end of the output. All of these are things that some compilers might let you get away with, but they're all at least potentially undefined. Is there some reason you'd *want* to call `printf` without writing `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: @KeithThompson; I am amazed that without `\n` at the end of output will invoke UB! (never knew that). But I don't want to call library functions without including their headers. And also, is using `int main()` instead `int main(void)` a constraint violation??

Comment: C11 7.21.2p2: "Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined." If the implementation requires it, the standard says nothing about the behavior if it's missing. `int main()` is not a constraint violation; it it as worst undefined behavior (and that's debatable). But `int main()` is an old-style non-prototype definition, which is obsolescent. All compilers I know of quietly permit it for backward compatibility, but `int main(void)` is better style.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Thanks for the information Sir. But down-voter has down-voted for wrong reason.

Comment: I don't know why they downvoted, but your answer doesn't mention the relevant issue that gcc replaces `sqrt(10)` to a constant, or that an actual call to `sqrt`, unlike `printf`, typically requires linking with `-lm`.