# Math library included but error undefined reference to `log'. Can it be the casting?

Tags: c, math.h

I have a function with the following code:

```
static void
calculate_lifetime(uint16_t p_weight){
  double param, result;
  param = (double) p_weight;
  result = log (param);
}
```

I include the math library, but when I compile I get the error:

> undefined reference to `log'

Am I doing something wrong when casting? When I remove param and put a number like 8 it compiles correctly.I'm compiling for Contiki.

Comment: When you compile, do you link to the math library?  Is there a `-lm` option?

Comment: Just including `<ath.h>` is not enough, you also have to link the math library (with `-lm` for gcc).

Comment: You're all right :). I'll post an answer for anyone using Contiki. I had to update the Contiki Make file and the corresponding cpu Make file.

Comment: @CodePorter if you use a constant many compilers can do the [calculation at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230849/is-maths-library-included-in-the-glibc-now/19230882#19230882) and thus avoid linking with `math.h`.

Comment: Remember that the `-lm` has to *follow* the source file name on the compiler command line.

Comment: With the code shown, the variable `result` is never used, so the compiler might end up optimizing the whole function body away -- and since it is static, it could simply not call the function and not generate any code for it.  If the function returned the result, all would be well.